# How to find opensource/software freedom GitHub alternatives?

Tags: github, publishing, microsoft, cloud

*Reviewers: the post was edited, now it asks for the most important selection parameters and not for a list.*

Now that [Microsoft bought Github](https://www.theverge.com/2018/6/5/17429054/microsoft-github-acquisition-memes-developers), I think programmers and coders favorizing software freedom and a better world <sup><sup>© ® ™</sup></sup> have a reason to switch their code sharing provider.

The question is, where.

Actually, having a git server is not a very big service, what the important was in the GitHub, the many possibilities to publish and share the code with others.

On which parameters should I watch, if I looking for a code hosting & sharing provider, and the software freedom is an important thing for me?

Comment: "Actually, having a git server is not a very big service" - I think to many open source projects, Github (and a few similar sites like it) are more than merely the Git server. It is usually the management of code in one or more (Git or otherwise) VCS repositories *plus* an issue tracker and possibly other organisational and presentation-related tools (think documentation wiki, file releases, etc.) *plus* a management system for associating user accounts with projects in such a way that the associated users can use some or all of the aforementioned facilities in the given project that counts.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Exactly this is what I want, but without the MS influence.

Comment: At first glance, this looks like a recommendation question (and indeed, maybe it is) which aren't well-suited to the Stack Exchange format. However, I think there might be an opportunity for an answer to point to the FSF's criteria for repositories, and talk about network effect in general, which would be on-topic and helpful. This would require a few edits to the question, though.

Comment: You know what would be a better world? One where amazing free services such as GitHub continue to be provided because their companies don't go bankrupt because they're well managed and integrated into development services which for-profit companies are willing to pay for. The FUD around all of this is ridiculous.

Comment: @curiousdannii 1) I don't believe that a bankrupt company could be sold for $7.5bn. 2) I simply don't believe in the big clouds provided my Big U.S. Companies, I think a lazy connected network of hosting providers would be a much better world. 3) Microsoft is evil. No, it is not a fair company working for fair profit by hard work. They are really evil. The list of their unforgivable sins could fill a book.

Comment: @Peterh There's a difference between being unprofitable and being bankrupt, but one leads to the other.

Comment: @curiousdannii Indirect influence can be converted to direct money, this made the Wikipedia, and maybe even the Stack Exchange, profitable. (Ok, the SE has some money from ads & personal services, too.) What is the common in the Github, SE and Wikipedia: all of them are a small company, typically with 100-200 employee, and they can somehow survive. I see no reason, why the github couldn't have done this. I think its founders wanted big money, now, this is why the company were sold. This can be reasonable, but doing this they should also accept, that many developers won't accept it.

Comment: @peterh Wikipedia is run by Wikimedia, which is a _not-for-profit_ foundation, which, by definition and intention, is _not_ profitable. There is absolutely no reason why a small company should be inherently more ethical than a big one. And in terms of Open Source, Microsoft buying GitHub does not change anything. The GitHub platform was never Open Source. In fact, I wouldn't be too surprised if Microsoft would release the platform under an Open Source license at some point. Wouldn't that be ironic?

Comment: @anothernode Yes, it would be. But instead of the imaginations that the wolf has no teeth, I would suggest to use Occam's razor. [Check this very non-profit link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish).

Comment: What's occam's razor good for if one doesn't even get the basic facts right?

Comment: @anothernode The most basic fact is: if you want to fight for the evil, then we won't be on the same side and we have not too much to talk.

Comment: Yeah, interesting link. I'll consult if I ever write a _history book_ on Microsoft.

Comment: @anothernode I've read some already. I lived some already. That was enough. This company shouldn't have ever existed. I want to live in a world, where it never existed. And I will.

Comment: @anothernode And now call me, for example, some fanatic. Call me, it is not a problem for me, how do you call me, because I know, if there will be ever justice on the Earth, the m$ won't have a place on that Earth.

Comment: *shaking head* The world is a little bit more complex than you imagine. Have a nice day.

Comment: @anothernode Yeah, there is a some complex network of lies showing that poor m$ is only a fair player wanting to produce profit and they are successful only because they are so good. *That is a really complex network of lies.* But the king is naked...

Comment: @anothernode Millions of people... programmers... engineers... driven not only by the money, but also by the belief in a better world... working together. They are few, compared to the masses, and they won't be ever so successful. But they remain human, and they change the world in a better direction, and not the blind people controlled by the money. This is the m$ is fearing from, this is why the github was bought... and this is why we have not too much to talk, and this is why my github account is now over. If you have belief, it is like the water. It cuts mountains through.

Comment: @anothernode This is why the github was bought. *It was like building a dam.* Everybody knows this, everybody feels this, even you know very well, that you are working for the evil now, but you ignore it.

Comment: Sorry dude, but you sound severely delusional.

Comment: @anothernode It is only your view, incapable or unwilling to handle, yes sometimes the whole world is damaged. Such a damage happened as the m$ became the top1 IT company, roughly at the early nineties.

Comment: [GitHub released the code for their self-developed load balancers](https://githubengineering.com/glb-director-open-source-load-balancer/)! Oh my god, I'm a prophet! :)

Comment: @anothernode In my view, GitHub went to the bad side for material advantages, thus their opensource balancer is now irrelevant. I simply want to live in a world where the m$ has never existed, and these are not "delusions", but my wish for a better, more free world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was motivated by @apsillers 's hint about the [GNU's ethical repository criteria](https://www.gnu.org/software/repo-criteria.html). They have also a list of criteria what seem not important for a simply cloud user (for example, the freedom of their javascript sources), but they are important for the second spot.

The criteria has a little bit of obvious influence from the side of the GNU (for example, saying "GNU/Linux" instead "Linux" is a positive thing by them - my opinion is, doing this is fair to the GNU, but has not too much to do with the freedom of a source hosting service).

The important thing to know, there no such thing as *"The Free<sup>1</sup> Source Hosting/Sharing Provider"*.

There is a set of possible candidates, and your choice should depend also on the actual project.

https://savannah.gnu.org seems very useful for "orthodox" software freedom projects. They check all their projects before inclusion and only really free projects can go there.

Semi-business projects could go for https://bitbucket.org . This is in the F, ("unacceptable") category at the FSF, however there is a strong argument for it, that it is the second largest free source hosting next to github. I found a significant disadvantage that it is painfully slow.

*A smaller, but much faster free source hosting alternative is the [https://gitlab.com/](https://gitlab.com). It gives exactly the same quick and perfect github feeling, except that even its frontend is opensource (a RoR app). People coming from the github will find it probably the best one.*

Typically, most Linux distros have some source hosting for their packaging, packages could go into there. (Like https://alioth.debian.org )

For Ubuntu packages, there is also the https://launchpad.net , although it is more like a package builder and ppa site than a git source hosting.

<sup>1</sup> Both as beer and freedom.

Comment: "Little bit of FSF leanings" in the GNU guidelines is quite the understatement...